# Rails route for partially scoped resource and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a resource where I want index/show to be public-facing but everything else to be scoped with '/admin'. I was expecting the following to work:

```
  resources :jobs, only: [:index, :show]
  scope 'admin' do
    resources :jobs, except: [:index, :show]
  end
```

And it does, to an extent. The only issue that I run into is that using form_for doesn't recognize the scope when doing a `post` for `:create`. It sets the action to '/jobs' instead of '/admin/jobs'.

This isn't a huge deal, as I can work around it by creating a specific create path and specifying that in the `form_for`'s url

```
  resources :jobs, only: [:index, :show]
  scope 'admin' do
    post :jobs, to: 'jobs#create', as: 'create_job'
    resources :jobs, only: [:edit, :new, :destroy, :update]
  end
```

Is there a better way to overcome this?

Edit: Here are my routes when if I don't specify a specific route for :create

```
       jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)                jobs#index
        job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)            jobs#show
            POST   /admin/jobs(.:format)          jobs#create
    new_job GET    /admin/jobs/new(.:format)      jobs#new
   edit_job GET    /admin/jobs/:id/edit(.:format) jobs#edit
            PATCH  /admin/jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
            PUT    /admin/jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
            DELETE /admin/jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#destroy
```

Comment: What about `form_for [:admin, :job]`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, specify an explicit url :

```
form_for @job, url: admin_job_path(@job) do |f|
```

but then you have to handle the difference between editing (update) and creating manually (different url).

So the best way is just to write

```
form_for [:admin, @job] do |f|
```

Comment: For both of these suggestions, visiting the page just gives me an undefined method for 'admin_job_path'. The path that's created instead of admin_job_path is simply 'job_path'. Not sure why, since :create is within the /admin scope.